Issue with Apache Flume Kafkasink
(org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.processDisconnection:667)  - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 0 t
erminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
Flume process which sends data to Eventhub stopped working. When checked the flume logs, I noticed the above error message. I make sure there is no firewall or network connectivity issue and also make sure the credentials to connect to Eventhubis working by establishing the connection via Azure Service Bus Explorer.
Not sure what is causing this error. Any help would be appreciated.
